# not able to show ip address on port menu

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-yun

i'm really going crazy for this problem!!!
On the port menu, in the arduino ide, i need to select the ip address of my arduino yun, but i get only the serial port in the list (COM13).

well, 
1 - i've reinstalled Bonjour
2- opened the port 5353 UDP in the firewall of windows 7
3 - reinstalled ide arduino
4 - upgraded the OpenWrt-Yun image on the Yún [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/YunSysupgrade)

it isn't still working... any suggestion for me???

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Well, probably, in my case the issue came from the os windows 7. After re-installed win7, and installed the right version of java, bonjour, bonjour browser and arduino ide, it worked very fine!!

Hope this helps!